# OutputStreamWriter alternative in Jenkins Active Choices Reactive Parameter

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I am making a POST API call to proxmox for an authentication token but as soon as I use OutputStreamWriter inside the groovyscript for the active choices parameter it breaks. This currently works on Groovy Script IDE. Are there any alternatives to using the OutputStreamWriter?(it is the only way I have found that has enabled the query to return me the token when passing the params)

```
def url = new URL(urlString)
    def conn = url.openConnection()
    conn.setDoOutput(true)
    def writer = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream())
    writer.write(paramString)
    writer.flush()
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

You can get the response with the following code run on the master node:

```
def command = 'curl -k -d root@pam&password=password $URL'
def response = command.execute().text
```